# How to load page with ads inside iframes (like ad.doubleclick) faster without losing income from ads?

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-events

How do I load load page with ads inside iframes (like `ad.doubleclick`) faster without losing income from ads?

Solution suggestion:
Insert dynamically iframe on `document.ready`/`document.load` with jQuery to the page.

Example:

```
<div>
  <iframe style="display:none;"  src='...' />
  <noscript><iframe  src='...' /></noscript>
</div>  
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('iframe').css('display','block');
 });
</script>
```

The problem of thissolution: lose income because user will see ad less time or will go to other page.

Which other solutions exists and which solution better?

Please answer only if you have such problem in big website that a lot of his income coming from ads or you can show big websites that making your solution.

Comment: *[Everybody...](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#benice)*

Answer (score 9):

You should create the `iframe` right after `body` as a static element. You can then move it into a container or position with css once the document is ready. You can either set its src statically (which will be the fastest) or with jQuery before the document is ready, and therefor the content of the `iframe` will load asynchronously while the rest of the page loads.

```
<body>
<iframe id="ad"></iframe>
<div id="right-bar"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
// set the src of the iframe
$('#ad').attr("src", ....);

// on document ready
$(function(){
    $('#ad').appendTo("#right-bar");
});
</script>
...
```

Edit: Just so there's no misunderstandings I will repeat myself: setting src with jQuery will be slower, and should only be done if you are loading the urls dynamically with ajax. Since Yosef didn't specify the source of these urls I took it for granted that they were loaded from an external source which was the reason he was using jQuery to add the iframe to begin with.

Answer (score 7):

Ads are usually based on whether they are loaded, and clicked through rather than how long they have been looking at them.

so:

1) Isn't really a problem

2) When looking on the big scale, you make a decision as core design rather than design of ads. So the question really is, do I support users with javascript disabled? If you do then your ads should also support javascript disabled.

With this in mind, I personally would go for the javascript loading the frame after your website, as adverts do tend to slow website loading times which is highly annoying for the user and probably effects SEO rankings